# No fitted curves with warning: "ggplot2: stat_smooth warnings: Computation failed in `stat_smooth()`: object 'weight' not found"

Tags: r, ggplot2, stat

I am trying to fit nonlinear curves to a list of scatterplots. I use 'gnls' to fit the nonlinear model. 'gnls' works well, but when I tried to use it as a smooth method in ggplot2. It gives warnings: Computation failed in `stat_smooth()`: object 'weight' not found. And the fitted lines are not showing in the plots. Here are my codes:

```
library(nlme)
library(ggplot2)
Specie <- c(rep("Soybean", 10), rep("Wheat", 10))
Total.biomass <- c(25, 65, 175, 290, 440, 600, 750, 840, 911, 920, 2100, 35, 120, 400, 1000, 1150, 1400, 1600, 1700, 1695)
LMF <- c(0.67,0.6,0.455,0.465,0.415,0.337,0.271,0.220,0.180,0.171,0.115,0.6,0.56,0.47,0.28,0.22,0.19,0.14,0.11,0.115)

dat_LMF <- data.frame(Specie, Total.biomass, LMF)

exp_decay <- function(a, b, x){
  return(a*exp(-b*x))
}

fit1 <- gnls(LMF~exp_decay(a, b, Total.biomass), data=dat_LMF, 
             params = list(a+b~Specie), 
             start = c(0.6, rep(0, 1),0.0025,rep(0,1)))

ggplot(data = dat_LMF, aes(x=Total.biomass, y=LMF)) + 
  geom_point()+
  facet_wrap(~Specie, scale="free_x")+
  stat_smooth(method = "gnls", formula=y~exp_decay(a, b, x), 
              method.args=list(params = list(a+b~Specie),start=c(0.6, rep(0, 1),0.0025,rep(0,1))), se=F)
```

Anyone has any experience using nonlinear smooth method in ggplot? Thank you!

Comment: Function `exp_decay` is missing.

Comment: The exp_decay function is added. Thank you!